# What is the English equivalent of "~っぺ"?

Tags: suffixes

According to romanjidesu.com, "っぺ" is a familiar suffix used after a personal name. What level of relationship is necessary to use this? Is this similar with adding -y in the name of the person? Example: Mike -> Mikey?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about English language not Japanese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would be shocked if there were an English equivalent of 「っぺ」.

The closest (which is not even so close) that I could think of would be "-ie", "-y", etc. with which you just add an extra ***vowel*** to a name or nickname.

What is strikingly different in Japanese name suffixes is the fact that they add whole new ***consonants*** as well as vowels -- 「っぺ」、「たん」、「ぴー」、「ぴょん」, etc.

I would imagine that an English speaker would feel more than strange if someone called him with an whole new extra syllable attached to his name instead of just "-ie" or "-y".  I would not even know how you would decide on what new consonants to use.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's something new that I'm adding to my list of suffixes to remember. Thanks. :)

Comment: Well, actually, we have a diminutive suffix '-kins' in English, but it's not as common as 'y/ie'.